# Gson.fromJson, how to use dynamic json value on my POJO class?

Tags: java, json, gson, pojo

gson class:

```
import com.google.gson.*;
```

myJson:

```
{
"time": "notime",
"query": {
     "pages": {
         "18302": {
             "title": "Car",
             "pagelanguage": "en"
         }
      }
}
}
```

Custom POJO class:

```
public class MyClass {
    public String time;
    public Query query;

    public class Query {
        public ? pages;

        //...
    }
}
```

Java code:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
MyClass data = gson.fromJson(myJson, MyClass.class);
```

What Class should i set to my **"pages" variable** to handle **dynamically changing** (for exp: "18302") json key?

Comment: Is the value of `pages` known? In other words, will it always be a JSON object with `title` and `pagelanguage`?

Comment: yes, the only chancing variable name is "18302"

Comment: Then I would use a `Map` with the value type being a POJO type that fits the JSON object with `title` and `pagelanguage`.

Comment: in fact, the "18302" can have a custom class too (like Query), so if i use Map than i lost the pojo tree. And i can't access to my custom class in "18302"?

Comment: Right, you'll have to check the keys.

Comment: in fact, https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&rawcontinue&prop=info&inprop=protection&titles=Car i want to convert this page to java pojo class, but page id is always changing...

Comment: How can the keys have classes at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a Map.

```
public class MyClass {
    public String time;
    public Query query;

    public static class Query {
        public Map<String, Page> pages; // <-- here

        public static class Page {
            public String title;
            public String pagelanguage;
        }
    }
}
```

`"18302": {...}` will be stored as an entry in the Map with the key being `"18302"` and the value being a new `Page` object.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to create a Page class, this will work:

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> pages;
```

Then to use it:

```
pages.get("18302").get("title") // "Car"
```