# Dynamic JSON value in POJO

Tags: java, json, gson, pojo

Having trouble with dynamic JSON values and translating that into POJO classes. My retrofit2 response comes up with null so I assume my structuring is wrong.

My expected JSON output:

`

```
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Intraday (5min) open, high, low, close prices and volume",
        "2. Symbol": "IBM",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2022-10-26 19:40:00",
        "4. Interval": "5min",
        "5. Output Size": "Compact",
        "6. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Time Series (5min)": {
        "2022-10-26 19:40:00": {
            "1. open": "135.0600",
            "2. high": "135.0700",
            "3. low": "135.0400",
            "4. close": "135.0700",
            "5. volume": "500"
        },
        "2022-10-26 19:05:00": {
            "1. open": "135.3500",
            "2. high": "135.3500",
            "3. low": "135.3500",
            "4. close": "135.3500",
            "5. volume": "106"
        },
        "2022-10-26 18:50:00": {
            "1. open": "135.0300",
            "2. high": "135.0300",
            "3. low": "135.0300",
            "4. close": "135.0300",
            "5. volume": "100"
        },
        "2022-10-26 17:50:00": {
            "1. open": "135.0300",
            "2. high": "135.0300",
            "3. low": "135.0300",
            "4. close": "135.0300",
            "5. volume": "200"
        }
    }
}
```

`

DailyQuote.java class

`

```
...



public class DailyQuote {

    @SerializedName("Meta Data")
    @Expose
    private MetaData metaData;
    @SerializedName("Time Series (5min)")
    @Expose
    private TimeSeries timeSeries;

    /**
     * No args constructor for use in serialization
     *
     */
    public DailyQuote() {
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param metaData
     * @param timeSeries
     */
    public DailyQuote(MetaData metaData, TimeSeries timeSeries) {
        super();
        this.metaData = metaData;
        this.timeSeries = timeSeries;
    }

    public MetaData getMetaData() {
        return metaData;
    }

    public void setMetaData(MetaData metaData) {
        this.metaData = metaData;
    }

    public TimeSeries getTimeSeries() {
        return timeSeries;
    }

    public void setTimeSeries(TimeSeries timeSeries) {
        this.timeSeries = timeSeries;
    }



}
```

`

MetaData.java class

`

```
...
public class MetaData {

    @SerializedName("1. Information")
    @Expose
    private String _1Information;
    @SerializedName("2. Symbol")
    @Expose
    private String _2Symbol;
    @SerializedName("3. Last Refreshed")
    @Expose
    private String _3LastRefreshed;
    @SerializedName("4. Interval")
    @Expose
    private String _4Interval;
    @SerializedName("5. Output Size")
    @Expose
    private String _5OutputSize;
    @SerializedName("6. Time Zone")
    @Expose
    private String _6TimeZone;

    /**
     * No args constructor for use in serialization
     *
     */
    public MetaData() {
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param _3LastRefreshed
     * @param _5OutputSize
     * @param _1Information
     * @param _4Interval
     * @param _6TimeZone
     * @param _2Symbol
     */
    public MetaData(String _1Information, String _2Symbol, String _3LastRefreshed, String _4Interval, String _5OutputSize, String _6TimeZone) {
        super();
        this._1Information = _1Information;
        this._2Symbol = _2Symbol;
        this._3LastRefreshed = _3LastRefreshed;
        this._4Interval = _4Interval;
        this._5OutputSize = _5OutputSize;
        this._6TimeZone = _6TimeZone;
    }

    public String get1Information() {
        return _1Information;
    }

    public void set1Information(String _1Information) {
        this._1Information = _1Information;
    }

    public String get2Symbol() {
        return _2Symbol;
    }

    public void set2Symbol(String _2Symbol) {
        this._2Symbol = _2Symbol;
    }

    public String get3LastRefreshed() {
        return _3LastRefreshed;
    }

    public void set3LastRefreshed(String _3LastRefreshed) {
        this._3LastRefreshed = _3LastRefreshed;
    }

    public String get4Interval() {
        return _4Interval;
    }

    public void set4Interval(String _4Interval) {
        this._4Interval = _4Interval;
    }

    public String get5OutputSize() {
        return _5OutputSize;
    }

    public void set5OutputSize(String _5OutputSize) {
        this._5OutputSize = _5OutputSize;
    }

    public String get6TimeZone() {
        return _6TimeZone;
    }

    public void set6TimeZone(String _6TimeZone) {
        this._6TimeZone = _6TimeZone;
    }

}
```

`

TimeSeries.java class

`

```
...
public class TimeSeries {
    @Expose
    private Map<String, date> dates;


    public TimeSeries(Map<String,date> dates){
        super();
        this.dates = dates;
    }
    public Map<String, date> getDates() {
        return dates;
    }
    public void setDates(Map<String,date> dates){
        this.dates = dates;
    }
}
```

`

And date.java class

`

```
public class date {

    @SerializedName("1. open")
    @Expose
    private String _1Open;
    @SerializedName("2. high")
    @Expose
    private String _2High;
    @SerializedName("3. low")
    @Expose
    private String _3Low;
    @SerializedName("4. close")
    @Expose
    private String _4Close;
    @SerializedName("5. volume")
    @Expose
    private String _5Volume;

    /**
     * No args constructor for use in serialization
     *
     */
    public date() {
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param _3Low
     * @param _1Open
     * @param _5Volume
     * @param _2High
     * @param _4Close
     */
    public date(String _1Open, String _2High, String _3Low, String _4Close, String _5Volume) {
        super();
        this._1Open = _1Open;
        this._2High = _2High;
        this._3Low = _3Low;
        this._4Close = _4Close;
        this._5Volume = _5Volume;
    }

    public String get1Open() {
        return _1Open;
    }

    public void set1Open(String _1Open) {
        this._1Open = _1Open;
    }

    public String get2High() {
        return _2High;
    }

    public void set2High(String _2High) {
        this._2High = _2High;
    }

    public String get3Low() {
        return _3Low;
    }

    public void set3Low(String _3Low) {
        this._3Low = _3Low;
    }

    public String get4Close() {
        return _4Close;
    }

    public void set4Close(String _4Close) {
        this._4Close = _4Close;
    }

    public String get5Volume() {
        return _5Volume;
    }

    public void set5Volume(String _5Volume) {
        this._5Volume = _5Volume;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "List:{" +
                "Open='" + get1Open() + '\'' +
                ", High='" + get2High() + '\'' +
                ", Low='" + get3Low() + '\'' +
                ", Close='" + get4Close() + '\'' +
                ", Volume='" + get5Volume();
    }

}
```

`

My retrofit2 enqueue responsebody for metadata works but when i look towards the TimeSeries it produces null results. I followed this: [Gson.fromJson, how to use dynamic json value on my POJO class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29178077/gson-fromjson-how-to-use-dynamic-json-value-on-my-pojo-class) , as it had similar JSON structuring of dynamic keys but to no avail. I am using GSON library and do not wish to use Jackson.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

your json text "Time Series (5min)" don't has a dates child,and this json structure is so complex。you can modify your timeSeries like this：

```
   @SerializedName("Time Series (5min)")
   @Expose
   private Map<String, date> timeSeries
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting, but how does changing the map name from dates to timeSeries change anything? And the SerializedName is also dynamic in the "5min" part being potentially 10min or 30 min or 60 min

Comment: emmm..., if SerializedName is also dynamic,your pojo class is useless,you can convert it to HashMap.class,like:new Gson().fromJson(ss, HashMap.class);